# Kernel ridge regression with matrix-vector data set $S := \{ X_i, y_i \}_{i=1}^{N}$?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick, ridge-regression

**Background**:

For Kernel ridge regression, I have normally come across the data-set given in vector and scalar form, i.e., $\overline{S}:= \{x_i, \overline{y}_i \}$, where $x_i \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\overline{y}_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, for example, I could do the ridge-regression as given here [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292843/regularized-linear-vs-rkhs-regression).

**My question**:

Can we do the same Kernel ridge regression but with a data set in matrix-vector form, i.e., $S := \{ X_i, y_i \}_{i=1}^{N}$, where $X_i \in M_{n,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $y_i \in M_{n,1}(\mathbb{R})$? If yes, can you prove it or give me a reference/paper?

Comment: Note: see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371082/kernel-ridge-regression-with-matrix-vector-data-set-s-x-i-y-i-i-1.